# How to update Navigation drawer Item from asynctask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, navigation-drawer

`OnCreate` I do:

```
incidentItem = new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1));
navDrawerItems.add(incidentItem);
```

and in

`onPostExecute`:

```
incidentItem = new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1), true, "10");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it does not work, no error, no update.

Comment: if I add it again `navDrawerItems.add(incidentItem);` it will add it to the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `navDrawerItems` is a `Collection`.

In your `onCreate` method, you create a new `NavDrawerItem`, and store a reference to it in the `navDrawerItems` collection.

In your `onPostExecute` method, you create *another* new `NavDrawerItem`, and do nothing with the reference. You call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but the adapter still has the reference to the old `NavDrawerItem`.

What you want to do in `onPostExecute`, is either:

- Retrieve the original reference, something like `navDrawerItems.get(0)`, and update the data in it;
  or
- Remove the original, and add the new reference, just as before.

Comment: great explanation, I wish you can add some code, I have no idea how to handle this.

Comment: which part do I need to add? did you see the code in my question

Comment: Parts of your adapter (not the getview method), and what do you do with the navdraweritems?